# Бот выдаёт неверный ответ

Tags: python, telebot

Когда пишешь `Новости`, думает, что такой команды нет. Получается она выполняется и сразу же пишет:

> "Я не знаю что ответить "

Код:

```
import telebot
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("не скажу")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Игры")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(" Новости")
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы помогать людям!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.text == ' Новости':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Новостей пока нет.")
    if message.text == ' Игры':

        # keyboard
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton( " Кубик")
        markup.add(item1)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мои игры:".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup= markup)
    elif message.text == ' Кубик':
        key = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for el in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
            but = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=el, callback_data=f'Число {el}')
            key.add(but)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Выберите число", reply_markup=key,parse_mode="Markdown")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def inlin(call):
    #print(call.data)
    if call.data.split()[0] == 'Число':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Кидаем кубик..." )
        my_random = random.randint(1,6)
        if my_random != int(call.data.split()[1]):
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(my_random) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)


# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Удалите строку `def lalalas(message):`. Либо повесьте на неё хендлер. В чём срочность-то?

Comment: команда новости выполняется. Но.. Выдает  else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')

Comment: Уберите эмоджи из проверки текста сообщения, вы же их не пишете?

Comment: А вообще смените заголовок на понятную проблему, без «срочно». Количество желающих вам помочь тогда немного возрастёт. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас идёт два `if` подряд: `if message.text == ' Новости':` и `if message.text == ' Игры':`.

Соответственно, при сообщении `Новости` у вас срабатывает первое условие, и вслед за ним срабатывает `else` второго, потому что бот не находит сообщение `Игры`.

Чтобы такого не было, нужно:

```
elif message.text == ' Игры':
```

Comment: ага, ясно. Теперь хочу добавить еще одну игру и пишет "underfiled name message" и теперь не знаю что делать.

Comment: код загрузил выше.

Comment: если вам ответ помог, примите его, нажав галочку слева. и для решения других проблем, не связанных с этим вопросом, лучше открыть отдельный вопрос

Comment: хорошо спасибо, буду знать